# How to get data from an Old DB to a new One with different coulmns settings?

Tags: java, mysql, json, database, spring

I'm using Spring Boot, MYSQL and Angular 7.

I have to redo the social network of my company taking data from their old DB.
I improved it changing some columns settings but I have to get every data for each user.

OLD DB JSON EXAMPLE:

```
{
***PROBLEM, have no idea why they do the first row like this***
"e92b088c-5546-47bc-a9cf-2dc6da22c594": {
    "uuid": "e92b088c-5546-47bc-a9cf-2dc6da22c594",
    "skills": [
        {
            "id": 64,
            "name": "C#",
            "certified": false
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "name": "ASP.NET",
            "certified": false
        },
        {
            "id": 73,
            "name": "Sharepoint",
            "certified": false
        },

    ],
}
```

}

NEW DB JSON must look like this:

```
{
"uuid": "e92b088c-5546-47bc-a9cf-2dc6da22c594",
    "skills": [
            {
                "id": 64,
                "name": "C#",
                "certified": false
            },
            {
                "id": 66,
                "name": "ASP.NET",
                "certified": false
            },
            {
                "id": 73,
                "name": "Sharepoint",
                "certified": false
            },

        ]
}
```

I have 16k rows and I need to associate the first row of the old JSON with my uuid in new JSON.

I don't know why they did the first row like that and I have no idea how to solve it.

Is it possible to do it in Java?

Comment: *PROBLEM, have no idea why they do the first row like this* - It's quite correct IMO. This is the ID of that object, so it should be the key. This also avoid unnecessary loops when you already know the exact id you are looking for.

Comment: @BackSlash ok, I got it so what do you suggest me to do?